# React mapping table with a second map function

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

I am trying to map this data into and table and i am having difficulty mapping the categories.
This is structure of the json.

```
     "id":"EONET_4639",
     "title":"Wildfire - Herkenbosch Village, Netherlands",
     "description":"",
     "link":"https://eonet.sci.gsfc.nasa.gov/api/v2.1/events/EONET_4639",
     "categories":[
        {
           "id":8,
           "title":"Wildfires"
        }
     ]
```

And this is my code. Can someone please tell me how to map through the categories.

```
{Object.values(eventData).map((row, index) => {
                  const labelId = `enhanced-table-checkbox-${index}`;
                  return (
                    <TableRow>
                      <TableCell padding="checkbox">
                      </TableCell>
                      <TableCell component="th" id={labelId} scope="row" padding="none">
                        {row.id}
                      </TableCell>
                      <TableCell>{row.title}</TableCell>
                      <TableCell>{row.description}</TableCell>
                      <TableCell>{row.link}</TableCell>
                      {Object.values(row.categories).map(c,index)=>{
                        <div>c.title</div>
                      })}
                    </TableRow>
                  );
                })}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to return in your map.

```
{Object.values(row.categories).map((c,index)=> return (
  <div>c.title</div>
))}
```

Moreover, your categories is an `array`, you dont need `Object.values`. 
Also, you can use short syntax in your case.

```
{row.categories.map((c,index)=>(<div>c.title</div>))}
```

Comment: I tried doing that aswell and it does not like the synatc has a red marked at => section

Comment: @gkhan, i have updated the syntax, try now once and let me know if any error comes.

Comment: Thanks this was the correct solution 
{row.categories.map((c,index)=>(<div>{c.title}</div>))}. Can you chnage your answer and i'll mark it as correct one

Answer (score 0):

Categories is an array, not an object. Also need to add a return or use the short syntax.

```
{row.categories.map(c, index) => (
  <div>{c.title}</div>
))}
```